# Postgis: Conflation of two vector layers into a single layer

Tags: postgis, linestring

If I have table A that I consider to be definitive and table B that may have some elements missing from table B but also has geometries that are "close" to those in A that I want to ignore. How could I merge the two tables to get a conflated table C?

For reference this is Openstreetmap ways married with road data from another set.

Would I  compare the start/middle and end points of the linestrings with table B to see if they were within X metres of any linestring in table A?

Comment: You might be able to use [ST_HausdorffDistance](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html) in conjunction with ST_Distance.

Comment: What would be your tolerance for keeping, discarding similar linestrings?

Comment: I would say +-20 metres in distance terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of comparing start, end and mid points of separate linestrings is a good one, and could be written as:

```
CREATE TABLE C AS
 WITH diffs (aid, bid) AS 
  (SELECT a.id, b.id 
    FROM roads_a a, roads_b b 
    WHERE ST_Distance(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom)) > 20 
    AND ST_Distance(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom)) > 20 
    AND ST_Distance(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(a.geom, 0.5),
                   ST_LineInterpolatePoint(b.geom, 0.5)) > 20
    AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 100)
 ) 
 SELECT a.* 
   FROM roads_a a WHERE id in (SELECT aid FROM diffs) 
 UNION
 SELECT b.* 
  FROM roads_b b WHERE id in (SELECT bid FROM diffs);
```

where [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) is used to get the midpoint of the lines. The final ST_DWithin in the with clause is used to only consider lines that are within 100 meters, with the hope that the spatial index will use this and not compare lines that are kilometers apart.

You could also try using the [Hausdorff Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html), and replace all of the point to point comparisons in the where clause with a single `ST_HausdorffDistance(a.geom, b.geom)>20`, for example, but this metric is a bit harder to understand.