# Is it possible to merge multiple polylines into one

Tags: line, gps, merge, route

I have vehicle GPS coordinates of the route. In my case vehicles can drive through one road multiple times, so overall it can look like round trips. Is there any way to merge two traces into one, so at the end there will be only one red line on the map, using tools like PostGIS, OSRM or something else?

Also, currently I don't see a way to filter traces programmatically before rendering them on map, by checking if trace already present near the road.

I'm new to this site and unsure how to classify this problem.

After some searching, looks like PostGIS function [ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints.html) can help to remove close coordinates, it has parameter `tolerance` so the coordinates within the tolerance value will be considered as duplicates.

[image: Map example]

Comment: There is conflation method too > see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132259/postgis-conflation-of-two-vector-layers-into-a-single-layer